# Open downloaded file from browser footer capybara selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

Is there a way that I can open a downloaded file from the footer bar?

I'm writing tests to test the download of a pdf in Chrome.  I also want to open the file to confirm the content within.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the file download location is default to some location.

You can use following method to cross check.

```
File f = new File("PathToFileorDirectory");
if (f.exists() ) {
    Process p = Runtime
           .getRuntime()
           .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "path of PDF file"");
   p.waitFor();
    }
else
system.out.println("File does not Exist");
```